# Sprite Kit - how do i make the sprite jump by clicking on the image

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make the image jump by clicking on the sprite, rather than clicking the screen to make it jump.

```
func jump() {
    Football?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Football")
    Football?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 2000))
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
}

func touchUp(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    Football?.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Football")
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
```

Comment: you must change "Football" to "football"

Answer (score 0):

this is a really basic way of testing if the sprite is touched

BTW your variable is named Football proper nomenclature says thay you should be using lower case variable names "football"

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        if Football.contains(touchLocation) {
            //jump code here
        }
    }
}
```